# C#: Adding an existing file to a specific folder in project

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, add-in, projects-and-solutions

I need some help from you awesome people. So I made an addin for Visual Studio 2012 which does the following:

When an .aspx extension file is open on the screen and you press the add-in

1) It will check if there is a resource file that is already present in the App_LocalResources folder

```
If Resource file exists:
    It will compare the .aspx file and the resource file and if something 
    is missing in the resource file it will add it
If Resource file does not exist:
    First it will create a new resource file. After that it will check
    the meta:resourcekeys on the aspx file and add them to the resource file
    after that it should add the file to the project under the 
    App_LocalResources folder
```

Here is where I'm stuck. When I use `AddFromFile` it will always add the file under the .aspx file. So let's say I'm working on a page called `Default.aspx` and I press on my add-in. My add-in will find the `meta:resourcekeys` and add them to the newly created resource file which is actually created in the folder `App_LocalResources`! After that when it adds it to the project, it **wont** add it under the `App_LocalResources` folder, instead it will add it under `Default.aspx`. I tried both `AddExistingItem` **and** `AddFromFile` which resulted in the same result. Can anyone help me?

EDIT: Ok so I've been using this code to add the file to my project:

`var currentObj = _applicationObject.ActiveDocument;`
`currentObj.ProjectItem.ProjectItems.AddFromFile(FilePath);`

Since I'm using ActiveDocument it adds the file *under* the file Default.aspx because I'm working on it. Any way to change this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using:

currentObj.ProjectItem.ContainingProject